# jquery-raty is not showing any stars

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add star reviews to my app using jquery raty and I can not for the life of me figure out why I can not see the stars on my restaurant review pages. I have also uploaded the star pictures to AWS

I downloaded and put the file jquery.raty.js into my app/assets/javascripts folder. Here is my show.html.erb file:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <%= image_tag @restaurant.image_url %>

        <h2>
             <%= @restaurant.name %>
        </h2>

        <p>
            <strong>Address:</strong>
            <%= @restaurant.address %>
        </p>

        <p>
            <strong>Phone:</strong>
            <%= @restaurant.phone %>
        </p>

        <p>
            <strong>Website:</strong>
            <%= link_to @restaurant.website, @restaurant.website %>
        </p>
        <%= link_to "Write Review", new_restaurant_review_path(@restaurant), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9">
        <% if @reviews.blank? %>
            <h3>No Reviews yet. Be the first to write one!</h3>
        <% else %>
            <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
                <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= review.rating %> ></div>
                <p><%= review.rating %></p>
                <p><%= review.comment %></p>
            <% end %> 
        <% end %>


    </div>
 </div>




<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_restaurant_path(@restaurant), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', restaurants_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>

<script>
    $('.star-rating').raty({
        path: 'https://pbukurasyelpdemo.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/stars', readOnly: true, score: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
    });
</script>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery.raty
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Here is my views/layouts/_bootstrap.html.erb

```
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
  href="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be loading jquery twice, once in application.js and once via the cdn.

Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: I have not had any errors come up. Just seems to load normally but there is no broken star links or anything. I added the file to my application.js file since I was reading through other tutorials of raty and people added that there